# Debugging multithreaded program in TCL using Komodo

Tags: multithreading, debugging, tcl, remote-debugging, komodo

I'm quite new in TCL world. I develop some existing server written in TCL.

Put it simple. There are two threads. The first one is the main thread and the second one is that I want to debug. It processes HTTP requests.

I'm using Komodo IDE. It looks like debugger is connecting only to the main thread. I set breakpoint on the line which is executed only by the second thread but debugger never stopped here.

How can I debug the second thread?

Can I switch threads when debugging?

Maybe I have to use remote debugging with some parameters?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: It looks like you're not getting many answers here. (I don't use Komodo, so I can't answer.) You might be better off asking ActiveState directly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now I use `puts` but it's not very convenient :/ Maybe you know other IDE with such debugging option?

Comment: @rzymek Tcl definitely need more powerful debugger then Komodo has. I asked question about other debuggers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213352/any-tcl-code-debugger-except-from-activestates Maybe I will get answer.